Photoelectron and electron in photoelectric effect
Could you please help me find some answers, as I have been stuck in this for a while and didn't get understandable answers.

what is the difference between the photo electron and an electron.

The vacuum, which is created for photoelectric effect experiment setup, is it a false vacuum?

If we have a photoelectric spectrometer to calculate energies of the ejected photoelectrons, does that consider the energy lost due to movement of photoelectron for distance between spectrometer and source?

do photoelectrons have spin angular momentum?



You should review the help section before posting another question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

A photoelectron is simply an electron which was emitted from some bulk material due to the photoelectric effect. This is not something which manifestly alters the properties of the electron - it is the same as any other.
What do you mean by false vacuum? The experiment is performed under vacuum simply to better enable detection of the electrons. They would not make it very far through the air due to collisions, hence the vacuum. It does not need to be "perfect" in order to improve detection (and no vacuum is truly perfect).
Necessarily, your detector can only tell you about the measured energy at the detector and not anything about what energy it may have had when it was emitted. In a vacuum with no electric/magnetic fields etc., then there should be no reason for the energy of the electron to have changed between emission and detection.
Given that photoelectrons are just normal electrons, they have spin just the same as any other electron.
